# Is it possible to use RoomDatabase to convert a cursor into an object?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have a dynamic query which I can't execute using the @Query so I will do it with something like

```
AppDatabase.getInstance().openHelper.readableDatabase.query(query).
```

Since RoomDatabase can return objects instead of a cursor, is it possible to use it somehow to convert an already existing cursor into a list of objects?
Or do I need to make my own method to convert the cursor to an object ?

Comment: uh. I'm pretty sure you should be using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I need, thank you !